# Working with hardlinks in *nix

Tags: hardlink

I have done the following operations:

> 1. echo "test" >> t1
> 2. echo "test2" >> t2
> 3. ln t1 l1
> 4. cp t2 t1
> 5. cat l1

To my surprise after overwriting t1 with t2 the hard link was still working. As per my understanding when you create a new version of a file the hard link is not pointed to the new version.

Why after using the cat command on hard link [after overwriting] the hard link is still valid and pointing to the content of the new t1 file?

Comment: this is strange indeed, I just did the same on OSX and got "test2" as the output of `cat l1`

Answer (score 1):

According to the manpage of `cp` on OS X, this is intended behaviour:

> -f
>
> If the destination file cannot be opened, remove it and create a new file, without prompting for
>         confirmation regardless of its permissions.  (The -f option overrides any previous -n option.)
>
> The target file is not unlinked before the copy.  Thus, any existing access rights will be
>       retained.
>
> -n
>
> Do not overwrite an existing file.  (The -n option overrides any previous -f or -i options.)

Meaning that, removing the target file before copying is not done by default. The hard link will only break if one of the files is removed.

In order to consistently get the behaviour you are trying to achieve, you **must** remove the target file before copying.

Comment: Can you please explain how this agrees with the following highly rated answer:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/108771/what-is-the-difference-between-a-hard-link-and-a-symbolic-link

Comment: "If you replace the other file with a new version (by copying it), a hardlink will not point to the new file."

Comment: That must refer to `cp t2 t3` which makes that `t2` and `t3` are separate inodes. In your example, `t2` and `t1` are also different inodes. `t1` and `l1` are the same, though, even after the copy operation.

Comment: A bit confusing what @vartec means with "if you *replace*", the only way that makes sense is if you copy and then move over the original.